# Keep item aligned vertically at same point when height of content changes

Tags: html, css, forms, css-grid, responsive

I am creating a form which has three steps (tabs), each tab contains a different part of the form and is a different height. I want the largest tab to be vertically centered on the page and the other two to be vertically aligned to the top of the largest tab. I've experimented with different CSS options but can't seem to get it to work, I've attached my code as well as a gif of my expected result. Thank you for taking the time to read this!

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="regForm" action="">

        <h1>Register:</h1>
        
        <div class="tab">Name:
          <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Contact Info:
          <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Fax" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Birthday:
          <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
          <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Expected Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid to define the layout and make all the tab above each other (on the same grid area) then rely on visibility instead of display.

You only need 2 CSS declaration added to your code:

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.visibility = "visible";
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[currentTab].style.visibility = "hidden";
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 300px;
  display:grid; /* added */
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
  visibility:hidden;
  grid-area:2/1; /* added */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="regForm" action="">

        <h1>Register:</h1>
        
        <div class="tab">Name:
          <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Contact Info:
          <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="Fax" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab">Birthday:
          <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
          <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
        </div>
        
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
          <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```